# How to avoid providing length along with char*?

Tags: c++, char

There is a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) which sends data to the server:

```
int send(
  _In_  SOCKET s,
  _In_  const char *buf,
  _In_  int len,
  _In_  int flags
);
```

Providing length seems to me a little bit weird. I need to write a function, sending a line to the server and wrapping this one such that we don't have to provide length explicitly. I'm a Java-developer and in Java we could just invoke `String::length()` method, but now we're not in Java. How can I do that, unless providing length as a template parameter? For instance:

```
void sendLine(SOCKET s, const char *buf)
{
}
```

Is it possible to implement such a function?

Comment: Are you looking for a C or C++ answer?  Confused by the tag shuffle and one of each answer.  Is your data just text or binary data with possible embedded zeroes?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Its c++, see the comments under David's answer. As far as the question about string vs ordinary data is concerned: From the OP's question and the name of the wrapper function I deduced that we are only talking about sending strings, but yes, the answers posted so far ar no general purpose wrappers for `send`.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you consider the necessity of remembering the string's length by yourself a bit weird, but I cannot help to wonder why you did not stumble across `std::string`. Did you never do a simple Google search for "C++ string"?

Answer (score 5):

Use std string:

```
void sendLine(SOCKET s, const std::string& buf) {
    send (s, buf.c_str(), buf.size()+1, 0); //+1 will also transmit terminating \0.
 }
```

On a side note: your wrapper function ignores the return value and doesn't take any flags.

Comment: Yes, I did that delibertely.

Comment: @stella: I forgot to account for the terminating `\0` character in the original answer. You'd probably also want to transmit that, so the receiving side knows, where the string ends.

Comment: @MikeMB: Actually, that depends on the documentation of `send`.

Comment: @MikeMB: In fact, if you look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, you will see that the example code uses `(int)strlen(sendbuf)`. So `buf.size()+1` is *wrong*!

Comment: @Christian Hackl: Only if you shutdown the socket after each string what is done in the example (actually they are just transmitting a binary stream, which doesn't have a terminating `\0` anyway. I don't see any guarantee in the documentation, that your string will always be sent in a single packet or that such a packet is exclusively reserved for the content on one single send commmand. I also don't know if a call to recv will always return the content of exactly one whole packet or if it can also return only a part of it or multiple ones together.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: It is certainly not wrong, but it might waste one byte.

Comment: @MikeMB: But if the other side does not expect a `'\0'`? Let's say you wanted to transmit the string "Hello world", and you used two consecutive `send` calls for two `std::string` objects, one containing "Hello ", the other one "world". Would `size()+1` not incorrectly cause the other side to receive "Hello \0world\0"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: It would receive two strings and then could concatenate them if necessary. In my opinion, if the purpose of the function is to transmit a string, then it should transmit a string and the other side should take care of concatenating them if necessary. Or you concatinate them in a local buffer before you send them.

Answer (score 3):

you can retrieve the length of C-string by using strlen(const char*) function.
make sure all the strings are null terminated and keep in mind that null-termination (the length grows by 1)

Comment: Well, I'm writing in C++. I can't C-funnction?

Comment: you can, but your question is a C one, not C++

Comment: @stella: wasn't your question originally tagged with c++? Or did I missread that?

Comment: @MikeMB: It was, and it is again. Someone made an invalid edit without consulting the OP.

Comment: well, you asked very specific question (how to retrieve the length of char*) which is a clearly C question. (btw it wasn't me who edited the tags)

Comment: It's not a C question unless the OP wants it to be a C question. If the OP tagged the question C++, and is compiling with a C++ compiler, then it is clearly a C++ question, even if a C solution would also work.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thanks for clarifying, I wanted to make sure, my answer was acutally a valid answer and forgot one can check tag changes in the version history.

Comment: just because "pan" is the word for "bread" both in Spanish and Portuguese , doesn't make any question about "pan" automatically Spanish related or Portuguese. in C++ , you would use std::string. if the question was general , like "how to create string-sending function" then yes, it could be both C++ and C. dealing with C-strings and WinAPI function  clearly makes the code C-like, that why the editor made it C. C++ has its own way of doing things, your question deos not go this direction

Comment: @stella: although I try to replace c-style strings in my functions wherever possible, `strlen` is also valid c++

Comment: Well, the OP tagged it with both and it's toggled back and forth now but neither change was initiated by the OP.  **shrug**  I keep wanting to fix the spelling of length, but I think I'll just slowly back away instead. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Nope, the OP only tagged it with C++. My edit was a rollback.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, you're right.  I misread when I saw both tags in the first edit.

Comment: @DavidHaim: I think your analogy fits my argument more aptly than it does yours. If someone asks you how to use the word "pan" in a sentence, you don't assume they are talking about Spanish, especially when they explicitly told you they are talking about Portuguese. And if someone asks you a question about `char*`, you don't make an assumption about whether they are talking about C or C++, you ask them. Now, that doesn't make your answer invalid. Because even though you wrote it as an answer to a C question, it also happens to be a valid answer to a C++ question.

Comment: and again I'll write - when you ask for the length of char* and use Winapi sockets, that makes your question a C one, even if C++ backward-compatible with it.

Comment: The only issue I have with an answer involving `strlen` is whether the data is just text or if it is binary and might include embedded zeroes which would make `strlen` the wrong choice.  `send` doesn't just send ascii data which is why there's a length parameter.

Answer (score 3):

***Edit:*** My answer originally only mentioned `std::string`. I've now also added `std::vector<char>` to account for situations where `send` is not used for strictly textual data.

---

First of all, you absolutely need a C++ book. You are looking for either the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class or for [`std::vector<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), both of which are fundamental elements of the language.

Your question is a bit like asking, in Java, how to avoid `char[]` because you never heard of `java.lang.String`, or how to avoid arrays in general because you never heard of `java.util.ArrayList`.

---

For the first part of this answer, let's assume you are dealing with **just text** output here, i.e. with output where a `char` is really meant to be a text character. That's the `std::string` use case.

> Providing lenght seems to me a little bit wierd.

That's the way strings work in C. A C string is really a pointer to a memory location where characters are stored. Normally, C strings are null-terminated. This means that the last character stored for the string is `'\0'`. It means "the string stops here, and if you move further, you enter illegal territory".

Here is a C-style example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f(char const* s)
{
    int l = strlen(s); // l = 3
    printf(s); // prints "foo"
}

int main()
{
    char* test = new char[4]; // avoid new[] in real programs
    test[0] = 'f';
    test[1] = 'o';
    test[2] = 'o';
    test[3] = '\0';
    f(test);
    delete[] test;
}
```

`strlen` just counts all characters at the specified position in memory until it finds `'\0'`. `printf` just writes all characters at the specified position in memory until it finds `'\0'`.

So far, so good. Now what happens if someone forgets about the null terminator?

```
char* test = new char[3]; // don't do this at home, please
test[0] = 'f';
test[1] = 'o';
test[2] = 'o';
f(test); // uh-oh, there is no null terminator...
```

The result will be **undefined behaviour**. `strlen` will keep looking for `'\0'`. So will `printf`. The functions will try to read memory they are not supposed to. The program is allowed to do anything, including crashing. The evil thing is that most likely, nothing will happen for a while because a `'\0'` just *happens* to be stored there in memory, until one day you are not so lucky anymore.

That's why C functions are sometimes made safer by requiring you to explicitly specify the number of characters. Your `send` is such a function. It works fine even without null-terminated strings.

So much for C strings. And now please don't use them in your C++ code. Use `std::string`. It is designed to be compatible with C functions by providing the `c_str()` member function, which returns a null-terminated `char const *` pointing to the contents of the string, and it of course has a `size()` member function to tell you the number of characters without the null-terminated character (e.g. for a `std::string` representing the word "foo", `size()` would be 3, not 4, and 3 is also what a C function like yours would probably expect, but you have to look at the documentation of the function to find out whether it needs the number of visible characters or number of elements in memory).

In fact, with `std::string` you can just forget about the whole null-termination business. Everything is nicely automated. `std::string` is exactly as easy and safe to use as `java.lang.String`.

Your `sendLine` should thus become:

```
void sendLine(SOCKET s, std::string const& line)
{
    send(s, line.c_str(), line.size());
}
```

*(Passing a `std::string` by `const&` is the normal way of passing big objects in C++. It's just for performance, but it's such a widely-used convention that your code would look strange if you just passed `std::string`.)*

> How can I do that, unless providing lenght as a template parameter?

This is a misunderstanding of how templates work. With a template, the length would have to be known *at compile time*. That's certainly not what you intended.

---

Now, for the second part of the answer, perhaps you aren't really dealing with text here. It's unlikely, as the name "sendLine" in your example sounds very much like text, but perhaps you are dealing with raw data, and a `char` in your output does not represent a text character but just a value to be interpreted as something completely different, such as the contents of an image file.

In that case, `std::string` is a poor choice. Your output could contain `'\0'` characters that do *not* have the meaning of "data ends here", but which are part of the normal contents. In other words, you don't really have strings anymore, you have a range of `char` elements in which **`'\0'` has no special meaning**.

For this situation, C++ offers the `std::vector` template, which you can use as `std::vector<char>`. It is also designed to be usable with C functions by providing a member function that returns a `char` pointer. Here's an example:

```
void sendLine(SOCKET s, std::vector<char> const& data)
{
    send(s, &data[0], data.size());
}
```

*(The unusual `&data[0]` syntax means "pointer to the first element of the encapsulated data. C++11 has nicer-to-read ways of doing this, but `&data[0]` also works in older versions of C++.)*

---

Things to keep in mind:

- `std::string` is like `String` in Java.
- `std::vector` is like `ArrayList` in Java.
- `std::string` is for a range of `char` with the meaning of *text*, `std::vector<char>` is for a range of `char` with the meaning of *raw data*.
- `std::string` and `std::vector` are designed to work together with C APIs.
- Do not use `new[]` in C++.
- Understand the null termination of C strings.

Comment: Nice, comprehensive answer - while reading it I was wondering, if one should pass `line.size()+1` instead of only `line.size()`, as one probably needs the null terminating character on the recieving side - depending on the exact socket type.